# Is there is way to get SUM() of column without GROUPING by joining multiple tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am getting `SUM()` of amount in `CrowdfundedUser` table by `GROUP BY CrowdfundID` but difficult to get `SUM()` because all columns are unique.

Crowdfund:

| CrowdfundID | GoalAmount | StartedDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | 10000 | 09/02/2022 |
| 5 | 20000 | 10/02/2022 |
| 55 | 350000 | 11/02/2022 |
| 444 | 541256 | 12/02/2022 |
| 54 | 78458 | 13/02/2022 |

CrowdfundedUser:

| ID | User ID | CrowdfundID | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 744 | 12214 | 9 | 1000 |
| 745 | 4124 | 5 | 8422 |
| 746 | 12214 | 55 | 784 |
| 747 | 12214 | 444 | 874 |
| 748 | 64554 | 54 | 652 |

CrowdfundiPaymentTransaction:

| CrowdfundedUserID | Invoice | Amount | PaymentDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 744 | RA45A14124 | 1000 | 09/02/2022 |
| 745 | RA45A12412 | 8422 | 10/02/2022 |
| 746 | RA45U14789 | 784 | 11/02/2022 |
| 747 | RA45F12457 | 874 | 12/02/2022 |
| 748 | RA45M00124 | 652 | 13/02/2022 |

My query :

```
SELECT
    c.CrowdfundID,
    SUM(cu.Amount),
    SUM(cpt..Amount)
FROM 
    Crowdfund c
INNER JOIN 
    CrowdfundedUser cu ON c.CrowdfundID = cu.CrowdfundID
INNER JOIN 
    CrowdfundiPaymentTransaction cpt ON cu.ID = cpt.CrowdfundedUserID
GROUP BY 
    c.CrowdfundID
```

Comment: You can use a windowed `SUM`; is that what you're asking about?

Comment: Side note: SQL Server 2008 has been *completely* unsupported for over 3 years now; you really need to finalise that upgrade path.

Comment: I have no idea what this question is about or what the issue is. and what's this about 'difficult to get SUM() because all columns are unique.' ?

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: Get sum of amount from second and third table

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.CrowdfundID,    
SUM(cu.Amount) OVER (    
ORDER BY c.CrowdfundID) Amount,    
SUM(cpt..Amount) OVER (
ORDER BY c.CrowdfundID)    CptAmount    
FROM Crowdfund c    
INNER JOIN CrowdfundedUser cu ON c.CrowdfundID = cu.CrowdfundID    
INNER JOIN CrowdfundiPaymentTransaction cpt ON cu.ID = cpt.CrowdfundedUserID
```